# Sql Syntax error unknown field list but looking for wrong field?

Tags: java, sql

So I created the following function to write to a database:

```
public static void updateBuyer(String ID, String name, Location latlong) {
    float lat = latlong.latitude;
    float lon = latlong.longitude;
    try {
        // new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        // conn =
        // DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdatabase?user=testuser&password=testpassword");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser,
                connectionPassword);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "UPDATE Buyer " + "SET latitude ="
                + Float.toString(lat) + " WHERE idBuyer in (" + ID + ")";
        String sql2 = "UPDATE Buyer " + "SET longitude ="
                + Float.toString(lon) + " WHERE idBuyer in (" + ID + ")";
        String sql3 = "UPDATE Buyer " + "SET Name =" + name
                + " WHERE idBuyer in (" + ID + ")";

        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql3);
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Lets say I passed the following parameters:
(12,craigs,location object)
Now when I run the function I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'craigs' in 'field list'
```

12 is the ID i retrieved from the databases earlier,
craigs is the random name I am trying to insert, and
location object is just a set of coordinates (lat,long)

Which leads me to think that it is looking for a field called "craigs" in the table for some reason, but why would it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got SQL like this:

```
UDPATE Buyer SET Name = craigs WHERE idBuer in (Whatever)
```

That's trying to copy the value from a column named "craigs".

Now you *could* just add apostrophes - but *don't*. Instead, use parameterized SQL with a prepared statement. That way you'll avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), your code will be simpler, and you'll avoid unnecessary string conversions which can cause problems, particularly with date values.

Additionally, you only need a single statement, which can update all three columns:

```
String sql = "UPDATE Buyer SET Name=?, latitude=?, longitude=? WHERE idBuyer=?";
try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    statement.setString(1, name);
    statement.setFloat(2, lat);
    statement.setFloat(3, lon);
    statement.setString(4, ID);
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

(Note that I've assumed you're actually only trying to update a single buyer - it's not clear why you were using `IN` at all. Also note that I'm using a try-with-resources statement, which will automatically close the statement afterwards.)

Additionally, I would *strongly *advise you to avoid just catching `Exception`. Catch `SQLException` if you must - but you'd actually probably be better letting it just propagate up the call stack.